# Http Server upgrade event not being called on Heroku servers

Tags: node.js, heroku

Why 'upgrade' event is not being called on Heroku servers?

```
var server = new http.Server();

server.on('upgrade', function(req, socket, upgradeHead) {
    // ...
});
```

Instead, the 'request' event is being called.

I am running the same script in my local machine and with websocket requests the upgrade events is being called.

Is it forbidden?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WebSockets are not yet supported by Heroku. See: [Using Socket.IO with Node.js on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku/).